# Removing value from list that isn't present using binary search, trying to raise error

Tags: python

The function removes value and that works fine, but when it tries to remove a value that is not present in the list it doesn't just throw an exception it gives me traceback and stops the run. The Exceptions are just custom exceptions. The binary search returns the index but i have to implement it.

1) remove_value() -> find -> binary_search -> remove_at()

```
 def remove_value(self, value):
    try:
        index = self.find(value)
        self.remove_at(index)
    except ValueError:
        raise NotFound()


 def find(self, value):
    if self.check_if_list_is_sorted() == True:
        high = self.size
        lst = self.arr[:]
        index = self.search_with_binary(lst, value, 0, high)
        return index


def search_with_binary(self, lst, value, low, high):
    if low > high:
        raise Empty()
    else:
        middle = (high + low) // 2
        if value == lst[middle]:
            return lst.index(value)     # lst[middle]
        elif value < lst[middle]:
            return self.search_with_binary(lst, value, low, middle - 1)
        else:
            return self.search_with_binary(lst, value, middle + 1, high)


def remove_at(self, index):
    '''Removes from the list an item at a specific location'''
    if self.size == 0:
        raise Empty()
    elif index > self.size-1:
        raise IndexOutOfBounds()
    else:
        for i in range(self.size - (index + 1)):       
            self.arr[index] = self.arr[index+1]       
            index += 1                                
        self.size -= 1                                
        self.arr[self.size] = 0
        return self.arr
```

Comment: "it doesn't just throw an exception it gives me traceback and stops the run" this is what it means to throw an exception. If you wish not to stop, you'll need to catch the exception and handle it however you want. You can simply `except Empty: pass` if you simply want to ignore them, or you can print some stuff, or whatever you like in the except block.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Are your custom errors subclasses of `ValueError`?

Comment: No, this was just one of my attempts to find out the issue :) that isn't there anymore.